# Broken CSS Menu on Hover - Flickering effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I scale this example down to Mobile size, a strange thing happens.

If you click 'Link2' from the Menu, you'll see its sub menu is cut off and if you try and hover over links lower down the sub-menu, intense flickering happens.

Why is this? Can someone help me resolve this?

Thank you for any help :-)

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qefszucv/

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('nav.primary').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Sports Menu</div>');
  $('nav.primary #menu-button').on('click', function(){
   var menu = $(this).next('ul');
   if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
     menu.removeClass('open');
   } else {
     menu.addClass('open');
   }
 });

 $('.inline .menu-item-has-children a').click(function () {

     //Expand or collapse this panel
     $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
     $(this).closest('li').siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
 });

});
```

```css
/* import */
/* line 1, sass/components/_reset.scss */
div, ul, ol, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* line 1, sass/components/_globals.scss */
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* line 7, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.left {
  float: left;
}

/* line 11, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.right {
  float: right;
}

/* line 15, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* line 24, sass/components/_globals.scss */
ul.naked, ol.naked {
  list-style: none;
}
/* line 30, sass/components/_globals.scss */
ul.horizontal, ul.inline, ol.horizontal, ol.inline {
  /**
  * For modern browsers
  * 1. The space content is one way to avoid an Opera bug when the
  *    contenteditable attribute is included anywhere else in the document.
  *    Otherwise it causes space to appear at the top and bottom of elements
  *    that are clearfixed.
  * 2. The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using
  *    `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.
  */
  /**
   * For IE 6/7 only
   * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
   */
  *zoom: 1;
}
/* line 31, sass/components/_globals.scss */
ul.horizontal li, ul.inline li, ol.horizontal li, ol.inline li {
  float: left;
}
/* line 65, sass/components/_espresso.scss */
ul.horizontal:before, ul.horizontal:after, ul.inline:before, ul.inline:after, ol.horizontal:before, ol.horizontal:after, ol.inline:before, ol.inline:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
/* line 71, sass/components/_espresso.scss */
ul.horizontal:after, ul.inline:after, ol.horizontal:after, ol.inline:after {
  clear: both;
}

/* line 42, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

/* line 42, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

/* line 42, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

/* line 47, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.circle {
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 6px solid;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  height: 156px;
  width: 156px;
}

/* line 62, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.columns img {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* line 68, sass/components/_globals.scss */
img.no-scale {
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: none !important;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

/* line 76, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.display-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* line 81, sass/components/_globals.scss */
.display-table .center-center {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

/* line 19, sass/components/_grid.scss */
.row {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1180px;
}
/* line 12, sass/components/_grid.scss */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* line 28, sass/components/_grid.scss */
.row .row {
  margin-left: -11px;
  margin-right: -11px;
  width: auto;
}
/* line 36, sass/components/_grid.scss */
.row.colapse .column, .row.colapse .columns {
  padding: 0;
}
/* line 40, sass/components/_grid.scss */
.row.colapse .row {
  margin: 0;
}

/* line 47, sass/components/_grid.scss */
.column, .columns {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 11px;
  padding-right: 11px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: left;
}
/* line 59, sass/components/_grid.scss */
.column.end, .columns.end {
  float: right;
}






















/* line 1, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.menu {
  font-family: "proxima-nova";
  padding-top: 3%;
  position: static;
}
/* line 8, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.menu a {
  color: #63615a;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
/* line 14, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.menu a:hover {
  color: #748d1b;
}

/* line 21, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.primary-item {
  margin-right: 2em;
  float: left;
}

/* line 27, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.primary-item:hover .sub-menu {
  max-height: 300px;
  padding-top: 27px;
  padding-bottom: 63px;
}
/* line 36, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.primary-item:hover .sub-menu a {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* line 41, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.sub-menu {
  max-height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 97px;
  left: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  /*background-color:rgb(228,228,228);*/
  background: #f2f2f2;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  list-style: none;
}
/* line 60, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.sub-menu a {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
/* line 73, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.sub-menu > li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
/* line 77, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.sub-menu > li > a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

/* line 84, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.sub-menu .sub-menu {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

/* line 92, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.sub-menu .sub-menu li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

/* line 97, sass/components/_navigation.scss */
.sub-menu .sub-menu li a {
  font-size: 14px;
}









@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  /* line 290, sass/_layout.scss */
  footer {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }

  /* line 291, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.columns {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* line 292, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.columns ul {
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
}


@media all and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2 / 1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* line 377, sass/_layout.scss */
  img.logo {
    min-width: 100%;
  }

  /* line 380, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.columns ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

  /* line 384, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary {
    padding-top: 0;
  }

  /* line 387, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary > ul {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
    transition: max-height 0.35s ease-out;
  }

  /* line 396, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary > ul > li > ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }

  /* line 400, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary.align-right ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }

  /* line 403, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary > ul > li > ul > li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }

  /* line 407, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary.align-right ul ul li a {
    text-align: left;
  }

  /* line 410, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }

  /* line 414, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li ul li a {
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* line 417, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }

  /* line 420, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary.align-center > ul > li {
    display: block;
  }

  /* line 423, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary > ul.open {
    max-height: 1000px;
  }

  /* line 426, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul {
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* line 429, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul > li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  /* line 433, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li a {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
  }

  /* line 440, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul > li:after {
    display: none;
  }

  /* line 443, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li.has-sub > a:after,
  nav.primary ul li.has-sub > a:before,
  nav.primary ul li ul li.has-sub:after,
  nav.primary ul li ul li.has-sub:before {
    display: none;
  }

  /* line 449, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li ul,
  nav.primary ul li ul li ul,
  nav.primary ul li ul li:hover > ul,
  nav.primary.align-right ul li ul,
  nav.primary.align-right ul li ul li ul,
  nav.primary.align-right ul li ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: auto;
  }

  /* line 459, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li ul li,
  nav.primary ul li:hover > ul > li {
    max-height: 999px;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
  }

  /* line 465, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li ul li a {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 35px;
  }

  /* line 468, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li ul ul li a {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 50px;
  }

  /* line 471, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li ul li:hover > a {
    color: #000000;
  }

  /* line 474, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary #menu-button {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #111;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* line 488, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary #menu-button:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 16px;
  }

  /* line 499, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary #menu-button:before {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 22px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 26px;
  }

  /* line 509, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sub-menu {
    transition: none;
    top: 0;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: white;
  }

  /* line 510, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sub-menu li {
    display: block;
  }

  /* line 511, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sub-menu a {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  /* line 512, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    padding-top: 0;
    display: none;
  }

  /* line 516, sass/_layout.scss */
  .primary-item:hover .sub-menu {
    padding: 0;
  }

  /* line 519, sass/_layout.scss */
  li.primary-item {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }

  /* line 523, sass/_layout.scss */
  .entry {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  /* line 527, sass/_layout.scss */
  .category-container {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}

















@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* line 537, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sticky-header {
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  /* line 541, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sticky-header .menu {
    background: url("../images/logo.png") 95% 10px no-repeat;
    background-size: 145px 55px;
  }

  /* line 547, sass/_layout.scss */
  footer {
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

  /* line 551, sass/_layout.scss */
  .logo {
    display: none;
  }

  /* line 555, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary #menu-button {
    padding: 30px 20px 10px 20px;
  }

  /* line 559, sass/_layout.scss */
  footer ul li {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px !important;
  }

  /* line 566, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary #menu-button:after,
  nav.primary #menu-button:before {
    display: none;
  }

  /* line 571, sass/_layout.scss */
  .columns img.logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    width: 145px;
    min-width: 145px;
  }
}





@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* line 603, sass/_layout.scss */
  li.primary-item {
    background: #ddd;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  }

  /* line 609, sass/_layout.scss */
  li.primary-item a {
    display: block;
  }

  /* line 612, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children a {
    color: #748d1b;
  }

  /* line 615, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    display: block;
  }

  /* line 618, sass/_layout.scss */
  nav.primary ul li ul ul li a {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 35px;
  }

  /* line 621, sass/_layout.scss */
  .sub-menu .sub-menu li a {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #ccc;
  }

  /* line 625, sass/_layout.scss */
  ul.sub-menu .menu-item-has-children {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  /* line 629, sass/_layout.scss */
  main {
    float: left;
  }

  /* line 633, sass/_layout.scss */
  .accordion-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* line 636, sass/_layout.scss */
  .primary-item > .sub-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="main-header " style="background-image:url('');">

   <div class="sticky-header">
   <div class="row ">

<nav class="medium-8 columns primary menu" style="background:red">
    
<ul class="inline naked">
 <li class="primary-item"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress">Link 1</a></li>      
 <li id="menu-item-142" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-142"><a href="#">This is Link Number 2</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=45">Sub1</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-77" class="sub-sub-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=47">Test</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=49">Test</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
   <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-79"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=35">Sub2</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-80"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=37">Test</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=39">Test</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=41">Test</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=43">Test</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
   <li id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-84"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=51">Sub3</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=53">Test</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=55">Test</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=57">Test</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=59">Test</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
   <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=61">Sub4</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=53">Test</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=55">Test</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=57">Test</a></li>
     <li id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=59">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-89" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-89"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=31">Link 3</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li id="menu-item-101" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-101"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=92">Test</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=97">Test</a></li>
   <li id="menu-item-100" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-100"><a href="http://localhost:8888/sportsy/wordpress/?page_id=94">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
                
                </div>
                
                    </div>
                    
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things, first you probably don't need `$(document).ready(function(){});` You can just use the dollar sign:

```
$('nav.primary').prepend('<div id="menu-button">Sports Menu</div>');

$('nav.primary #menu-button').on('click', function(){
    var menu = $(this).next('ul');
    if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
      menu.removeClass('open');
    } else {
      menu.addClass('open');
    }
});

$('.inline .menu-item-has-children a').click(function () {

    //Expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).closest('li').siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
});
```

Next, you can probably replace this:

```
if (menu.hasClass('open')) {
    menu.removeClass('open');
} else {
    menu.addClass('open');
}
```

With this:

```
menu.toggleClass('open');
```

Flickering is happening because the menu is too far from the dropdown.  I'd remove the css top value in sub-menu.

The slowdown of animation is the thing I'm not entirely sure about but I think it's working much harder than it should to achieve the animation.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I have updated with the CSS but the flickering continues: http://jsfiddle.net/qefszucv/1/ Help?

Comment: Whoops, didn't select the menu properly however you'll need to actually find the `.sub-menu` in the css code and completely remove the `top:97px;` property.  Though it only helps the hover state.

Comment: I'm sorry -- **what**? *A couple of things, first you probably don't need $(document).ready(function(){}); You can just use the dollar sign*

Comment: @fauxserious I removed it as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/qefszucv/5/ Still flickering unfortunately.

Comment: Found a fix :-) Will leave Answer below shortly !

Comment: @BramVanroy -- I'm sorry, what?

Comment: `$(document).ready` has nothing to with using the dollar sign or not. It is paramount to use a document ready call if you don't want broken functionality *especially* if you are calling the script from your head. If the script is executed when it's loaded (without doc.ready) and the elements haven't been loaded yet, your scripts won't work. Therefore, you can use document ready to wait till the document is ready. I have no idea why you think those things are even closely related.

Comment: The perils of being self taught.